# How to remove the ‘leave site ’ pop up While updating the url of the current active page in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for google calendar .
After an event I need to transverse to a particular url
So I use chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: ‘myurl’}) for updating the url of the current page.
But while updating the url , leave site pop up which is a default pop up for the browser is coming
Kindly suggest a way to remove it while updating the url in chrome extension

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this is something to be handled by the extensions API so please star [crbug/1031791](https://crbug.com/1031791). Meanwhile we can use the workarounds listed below.

#### Simplistic approach is to clear `window.onbeforeunload`

Works only for some sites.

Extension script (popup or background):

```
function clearUnloadPrompt() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: `(${() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = 'window.onbeforeunload = null';
        document.documentElement.appendChild(script).remove();
      }})()`,
      runAt: 'document_start',
    }, () => {
      chrome.runtime.lastError;
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

clearUnloadPrompt().then(() => {
  chrome.tabs.update({url: 'https://www.example.org/'});
});
```

#### Full exterminatus approach is to register `beforeunload` before the page does

Should work everywhere but the downside is that it requires a content script on all URLs where your extension needs to update the URL. Although not a problem if you already request these host permissions in manifest.json for your extension's main functionality.

manifest.json excerpt:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

(don't forget to use the URL patterns that you actually need instead of `<all_urls>`)

content.js:

```
const pageEventId = chrome.runtime.id + Math.random;

runInPage(suppressor, pageEventId);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  if (msg === 'suppressBeforeUnload') {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event(pageEventId));
  }
});

function runInPage(fn, ...args) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.textContent = `(${fn})(${JSON.stringify(args).slice(1, -1)})`;
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
  script.remove();
}

function suppressor(pageEventId) {
  let suppressBeforeUnload;
  window.addEventListener(pageEventId, () => {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    suppressBeforeUnload = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
    if (suppressBeforeUnload) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  });
}
```

extension script (popup or background):

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'suppressBeforeUnload', () => {
  chrome.runtime.lastError;
  chrome.tabs.update({url: 'https://www.example.org/'});
});
```