# Prevent dom-event from reaching window in capture phase

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Is it possible to prevent an event from reaching listener set at `document.window` with capturing enabled?

### Context

I am working on a chrome extension where I add some dom element (including some input element) to the dom from content-script. In a page, there is an event listener attached to the `document.window` with capture enabled, that listener takes away focus form my input element on any `keydown` event. As a result my input element is basically not working. I need to prevent that event from reaching the listener at window somehow.

Comment: Simply add your listener before the page adds its own. You should set `run_at` of your content script to `document_start` of course and add the listener right away, then activate it as needed, see an example in [How to remove the ‘leave site ’ pop up While updating the url of the current active page in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487374)

Comment: @wOxxOm - That answer doesn't seem directly applicable (in the duplicates sense), maybe post a quick answer here showing how you'd do it? (Sounds very promising.)

Comment: To make an answer I would need an [MCVE](/help/mcve) from the question's author. Hopefully the example is sufficient so the author can adapt it and then add an answer.