# Close chrome window using extension API without "Leave Site?" prompt

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension background page that closes a window:

```
chrome.windows.remove(windows[i].id);
```

Whenever I run this, I get an alert that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTGCo.png) if one or more pages have this prompt enabled. How do I circumvent this, so that tabs are closed without prompt? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use this answer: [How to remove the ‘leave site ’ pop up While updating the url of the current active page in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60486953)

Comment: @wOxxOm I am trying to find a solution that uses the extension api, not injecting scripts into tabs. Not to mention, I am aiming to close a window, not seperate tabs, and you can't "inject scripts into a window. "

Comment: There's no such API. You'll have to inject the code into each tab of the window.